# Jackrabbit Oracle Integration Issue

Tags: oracle, jackrabbit

I am trying to configure jackrabbit 2.6.3 to use oracle 11g. When I try to login to repository I get an error. Here is my code

```
Repositoryrepository = new TransientRepository(new File(repositoryXML));

try {
    session = repository.login(credentials());

 } catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Here is the error I get.

```
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: File system initialization failure.
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigurationParser$6.getFileSystem(RepositoryConfigurationParser.java:1168)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfig.getFileSystem(RepositoryConfig.java:916)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:262)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.create(RepositoryImpl.java:589)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository$2.getRepository(TransientRepository.java:232)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository.startRepository(TransientRepository.java:280)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository.login(TransientRepository.java:376)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.AbstractRepository.login(AbstractRepository.java:123)
    at com.bestbuy.richmedia.config.RMConfig.repository(RMConfig.java:83)
    at com.bestbuy.richmedia.config.RMConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d4d2798e.CGLIB$repository$0(<generated>)
    at com.bestbuy.richmedia.config.RMConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d4d2798e$$FastClassByCGLIB$$508f7f89.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
    at com.bestbuy.richmedia.config.RMConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d4d2798e.repository(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1031)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:927)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:298)
    at com.bestbuy.richmedia.config.RMConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d4d2798e.repository(<generated>)
    at com.bestbuy.richmedia.config.RMConfig.session(RMConfig.java:97)
    at com.bestbuy.richmedia.config.RMConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d4d2798e.CGLIB$session$1(<generated>)
    at com.bestbuy.richmedia.config.RMConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d4d2798e$$FastClassByCGLIB$$508f7f89.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
    at com.bestbuy.richmedia.config.RMConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d4d2798e.session(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1031)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:927)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.FileSystemException: failed to initialize file system
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DatabaseFileSystem.init(DatabaseFileSystem.java:207)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigurationParser$6.getFileSystem(RepositoryConfigurationParser.java:1165)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.CheckSchemaOperation.run(CheckSchemaOperation.java:81)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DatabaseFileSystem.init(DatabaseFileSystem.java:194)
    ... 91 more
```

Here is my repository.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE Repository
          PUBLIC "-//The Apache Software Foundation//DTD Jackrabbit 2.0//EN"
          "http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/repository-2.0.dtd">


<Repository>

    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.OracleFileSystem">
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <param name="user" value="cms"/>
        <param name="password" value="cms"/>
        <param name="schema" value="cms"/>
    </FileSystem>

    <!--
        data store configuration
    -->
    <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.OracleFileSystem">
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <param name="user" value="cms"/>
        <param name="password" value="cms"/>
    </DataStore>

    <!--
        security configuration
    -->
    <Security appName="Jackrabbit">

        <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager" workspaceName="security">
        </SecurityManager>

        <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.DefaultAccessManager">
        </AccessManager>

        <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.DefaultLoginModule">
            <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous"/>
           <param name="adminId" value="admin"/>
        </LoginModule>
    </Security>

    <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default"/>

    <Workspace name="${wsp.name}">

        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.OracleFileSystem">
            <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
            <param name="user" value="cms"/>
            <param name="password" value="cms"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.home}_"/>
        </FileSystem>

        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager">
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
            <param name="user" value="cms"/>
            <param name="password" value="cms"/>
            <param name="tablespace" value=""/>
            <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.home}_"/>  
        </PersistenceManager>

        <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
            <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
            <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
        </SearchIndex>
    </Workspace>

    <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">

        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
            <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/version" />
        </FileSystem>

        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager">
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
            <param name="user" value="system"/>
            <param name="password" value="richmedia"/>
            <param name="tablespace" value=""/>
            <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_"/>
        </PersistenceManager>
    </Versioning>


    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/index"/>
        <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
    </SearchIndex>

    <Cluster id="node1">
        <Journal class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.journal.MemoryJournal"/>
    </Cluster>
</Repository>
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the schema parameter is required for the persistence manager:

```
<PersistenceManager ...
    .....
    <param name="schema" value="oracle"/>
</PersistenceManager>
```

Comment: made multiple changes to my repository.xml for this to work. Also all insert, select, update needs to be granted to oracle schema user. Here is my working repository.xml